# In Huawei phone (Android), app got 'HttpHostConnectException: Connection refuse' after about one hour

Tags: android, service, httpclient, huawei-mobile-services

I developed one simple android app which uses a service to keep running and sending some gps messages to azure servicebus by azure provided rest webapi in time interval of 15 min.
There is no issue in Samsung phone. But I found an issue in China Huawei phone which I cannot resolved that. Issue is:
after app service running about 1 hour, when app tried to send data to azure servicebus by apache Http client, always got exception of 'HttpHostConnectException: Connection refuse'.

Note:
From log, I can confirm that the host service is alive, and the network of phone is fine also. Only that my app cannot send data with that exception after normal work for about one hour. This issue is only found in Huawei phone.

Please help to give any suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Dont let the service running all the time. Schedule alarms in 15 minutes interval which sends the data (stil bad practice but better than non-stop service)